# Is it possible to convert ( Type cast) REF Data type from a Stored procedure to Custom Java objects?

Tags: java, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a stored procedure declared output parameters with REF cursor (Ref data type) and I need to convert or type cast it to Custom Java object instead of plain Objects as Object[].

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: [edit] your question and post the declaration of your stored procedure.